# php multiple file upload path error

Tags: php

```
$tl = $_POST['title'];
$im = 'imag' . $id;

$query8 = "INSERT INTO media (fldr,title) VALUES ('{$im}','{$tl}')";
$result8 = mysql_query($query8, $connection);

mkdir("uploads/$im");
$path = "uploads/$im";

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024 * 100; //100 kb

// Upload directory
echo $path;
$count = 0;

// Loop $_FILES to execute all files
foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f = > $name) {
    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
        continue; // Skip file if any error found
    }
    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {
        if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
            $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
            continue; // Skip large files
        } elseif (!in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats)) {
            $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
        } else {
            // No error found! Move uploaded files 
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path . $name)) {
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded files
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> The images are not uploaded in given path. Images are uploaded to parent directory(uploads). I need to upload to created directory. Please help me..

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name)`

Comment: Please use the permission with command `mkdir ($dir, 0744);` or use `chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate the path and filename using a [directory separator](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php), like so:

```
if (move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name
)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change following code. You have to put path separator between $path and $name

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path . "/" . $name)) {
        $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded files
   }
```